# How to work with multiple EditText using addTextChangedListener in android

Tags: android

I have 3 `EditText` named `editTextA , editTextB and editTextC` . What I want to do is when text changes on either one of the EditTexts, the other two to update.

It is working correctly with single addTextChangedListener for editTextA and updating editTextB. But when I add another addTextChangedListener to editTextB, it is not working. My app crashed. I used `hasfocus()` method to find that which `EditText` is currently focused but same result.

Comment: you are in infinite loop.

Comment: can you provide your code and error log for better help ?

Answer (score 1):

you problem is infinite loop.

1. EditTextA changes
2. onTextChanged A called.
3. change text of EditTextB
4. onTextChanged B called.
5. change text of EditTextA
6. Goto 2

Answer (score 0):

While I'm agree with Mahdi-bagvand, I had same problem and you need to put an **ending condition**. For example for me it was the `length` of one `EditText`. Without putting an ending condition this will be an infinite loop and your app will crash.